# In Opera 18 how do you bookmark a page?

Tags: bookmarks, opera

In Opera 18 how do you bookmark a page? I [red here](http://help.opera.com/Windows/9.00/en/bookmarks.html) it used to be Ctr+D but that didn't work. I notice there's an "add to stash" icon but I have no clue what stash is. How can you remember a page so it can be visited in the future and give it an easy to remember name?

Comment: Add to Stash (heart shaped icon on the URL bar) is the Bookmark. Opera has 2 options, either as Speed Dial (first splash page when you open new tab), or Stash (the heart-shaped thing). Once you added it into Stash, when you open new tab, it will default to Speed Dial. Then next to the speed dial, there is a Stash tab. Click on it, it will have all things you have "Stash"ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bookmark is going into speed dial as they have decided it in new version so there is no bookmarkbar anymore. From this [article](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2428329,00.asp) I came to know about this as I don't use Opera

`One help is the browser's bookmark converter tool: Just like it sounds, this will convert your existing bookmarks from another browser to Speed Dial entries. But it doesn't just add new tiles for each site in your bookmarks; instead it creates a tile that expands to show the bookmarks.`

opera developer is trying to improve their bookmark system as soon as possible stated in the article.

**Stash from the article:**
`Stash is similar to the Reading List features I've been seeing appear in products like Windows 8, Safari, and mobile browsers. A heart icon always rests at the rightmost end of the address bar at all times; when you're at a page you have a mind to come back to later, just tap the heart. After that, when you open a new tab, you can click the Stash button at top center to see rows of your stashed sites' headers.`